# HTML5 audio detecting default controls

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am using the default controls in my project, the problem is at least some mobile browsers (chrome and adbock browser on android) lack a [standard control](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_controls.asp), volume; it only has mute... Is there a way to detect the lack of a volume option or do I have to check the useragent in javascript to and set the volume to 100% so they are not locked at my default volume of 25%

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do this natively and the user-agent is not reliable. The UI provided by the browser may also change in appearance and behavior over time.

The only way to fully control the player's UI is to build a custom one.